# How To Select Data based on Groupby and some condition in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get data from an SQL table based on self join. Here is my example which can explain the problem in detail.

Table1:

```
CustNo|State|City|Year2014|Budget2014|Year2015|Budget2015|Year2016|Budget2016
123   |BW   |LA  |2014    |6789.87   |NULL    |NULL      |NULL    |NULL
234   |HH   |SS  |2014    |877.67    |NULL    |NULL      |NULL    |NULL
123   |BW   |LA  |NULL    |NULL      |2015    |8789.87   |NULL    |NULL
234   |HH   |SS  |NULL    |NULL      |2015    |569.45    |NULL    |NULL
```

From the above input I want the following output:

```
CustNo|State|City|Year2014|Budget2014|Year2015|Budget2015|Year2016|Budget2016
123   |BW   |LA  |2014    |6789.87   |2015    |8789.87   |NULL    |NULL
234   |HH   |SS  |2014    |877.67    |2015    |569.45    |NULL    |NULL
```

As we can see, for every year only the value of `Budget` field changes for a particular customer. I want to fetch the records in one row for one customer.
I am not sure how I can get output like this.

Comment: is table1 an intermediate result? if so, please show the original table.

Comment: You generally want to return different values for the same fields in rows rather than columns.  Eg:  You should have a `Year` and `Budget` column with a row for each `Customer` and `Year` combination.

Comment: Agree with @iamdave. Poor design on the table structure. Group By would work better with combined columns for `Year` and `Budget`.

Comment: @iamdave i agree its a poor design but i can do anything with that or yes lets say If values for Year column is coming in only one column not as before shown in my post .  I am Posting here the Original query through which i am getting the data for both the Years in two rows what i want is to get data in on row..is this possible anyways:  Here is my quey: SELECT Distinct *
FROM Table1  a
Full JOIN Table1  b 
 On a.IK = b.IK and
      a.State = b.State and
       a.CustomerName = b.CustomerName and
        a.City = b.City      
WHERE a.Year <> b.Year

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `group by`.  Here is one method:

```
select CustNo, State, City,
       max(Year2014) as year2014,
       sum(Budget2014) as Budget2014
       max(Year2015) as year2015,
       sum(Budget2015) as Budget2015,
       max(Year2016) as year2016,
       sum(Budget2016) as Budget2016
from t
group by CustNo, State, City;
```

Comment: With this approach i am getting two rows with the values for 2015 and 2014 is it not possible to get all the data in one row

Comment: @swat . . . With your sample data, you will not get duplicate rows.  Your comment suggests that `city` and/or `state` are also changing (or that the values look the same but contain "invisible" characters).

Comment: Yes But as you can see for example  for  CustNo = 123, State=BW ,City= LA i am having budget Field different for year 2014 and 2015 this means somewhat these two rows are almost same but different values my question is is there any way with which i can get result in one row  same CustNo.,City,State ..i am very new to the Programming world ..So please dont mind if there is any stupidity from my side

Comment: Or Lets Say i am having only one column as Year in which i am storing value for     2014,2015  and   2016  here is my query which is getting me 2 rows for the same Customer,City,State but different Years    SELECT Distinct *
FROM Table1  a
Full JOIN Table1 b
 On a.IK = b.IK and
      a.State= b.State and
       a.CustomerName = b.CustomerName and
        a.City= b.City    
WHERE a.Year <> b.Year                                                                      is there any way to get all the data in one row